# "POSIX file" works in Applescript Editor, not in XCode

Tags: applescript, xcode4.2, applescript-objc

Try this:

1. Make a new XCode4 Applescript project.  In the delegate, paste this code:

   ```
   on doIt_(sender)
       set goodHFSLoc to (path to desktop folder)
       set test1 to (POSIX path of goodHFSLoc)
       log "test1:"&test1
       set theJSPath to "/Users/dave/Desktop/MakeTSLabels.js"
       set jsHFSFile to (POSIX file theJSPath)
       set test2 to (POSIX path of jsHFSFile)
   end doIt_
   ```
2. Hook this method up to a button in the UI window.
3. Run the program
4. Click the button, and you should get this error:

   ```
   Can’t get POSIX path of class "NSObject".
   ```
5. Put the same code (minus the "on" and "end" lines) into AppleScript editor, and it runs fine.

Apparently, "POSIX file" in ApplescriptObjC doesn't make a file object as the language specification [requires](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-SW15).  Instead it makes an NSObject.

I need to have an applescript file specifier to provide to Adobe Illustrator's `do javascript` command, and I need to use NSBundle's functions to get the javascript file, which is packaged in my application bundle.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see the same behavior in a **Finder** or **System Events** tell statement.  The solution is the same for ASObjC - you need to use it as a coercion:

```
set jsHFSFile to (theJSPath as POSIX file)
```